# Windows 8 HTML5 / JavaScript Canvas Tutorial on Windows 8 Dev Center Doesn't Work

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to work through this tutorial on the Windows 8 Dev Center: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452750.aspx

But haven't gotten past the first step. In my HTML5 file I have:

```
<canvas id="can1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

In my JavaScript file I have:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("can1");
var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8. I get the following error: "0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getContext' of undefined or null reference"

This is exactly what the tutorial says to do. Why am I getting an error?

Comment: where in your JavaScript file did you add the code? is the HTML file including that JavaScript file in a <script> tag?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 with the blank template which creates a separate HTML, JavaScript, and CSS file. The HTML and JavaScript are completely separate.

Comment: onactivated did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the blank template (as noted in your comment), then placing the suggested demo code in the onactivated event should work.  The following should display white line from the top left to bottom right corner of a black box.

in default.html:

```
<body>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <canvas id="can1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
```

in default.js, within the app.onactivated method:

```
app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }

        var myCanvas = document.getElementById("can1");
        var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

        myContext.fillStyle = '#000';
        myContext.strokeStyle = '#fff';
        myContext.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        myContext.lineWidth = 3;
        myContext.fill();

        myContext.moveTo(0, 0);
        myContext.lineTo(500, 500);
        myContext.stroke();

        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};
```